# Add the Firebase iOS SDK (4.3.0 or higher) or Unity Plugin (6.15.0 or higher), then build, run, and crash your app

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate with Firebase Crashlytics.

I added the run scripts as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started). then installed the pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

I configured the Firebase APIs:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

I ran the app. the messages on the console seems to be ok.

But when I open the Crashlytics tab in the firebase console. I only get the message in the question title.

[image]

This is what I have in my `Podfile.lock`:

```
- Firebase (6.33.0):
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the dSYM to the debug file the Debug mode.

> dSYM (Debug Symbolification) is needed to reverse symbolication of the
> code in crash.

[image]

Message states that you need to crash your app. Add the crash code on an ***event not on an app launch***:

```
fatalError()
```

**Note:** Crashes doesn't get reported:

> 1. If Xcode is connected to the app.
> 2. It only get reported in the next app launch.

**Steps:**

> 1. Run the app using Xcode.
> 2. Disconnect it from Xcode by clicking stop.
> 3. Re-launch the App manually.
> 4. Crash your app.
> 5. Re-launch it so the crash get reported.

***Info. gathered from api docs.***

Comment: I have same issue, is there any solution

Comment: you need to do this on the answer. and I will add few things to the answer now.

Comment: @hasan .. Tried the following but with no luck , Still getting the same message

Comment: مش عارف يا عنكبوت. اكثر من هيك مافي :)