# Add the Firebase iOS SDK (4.3.0 or higher)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to implement Crashlytics as per Firbase doc.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

All Steps performed :

Installed Pods:

pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

In App Delegate:

```
  import Firebase

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
     }
```

Added Runscript:

```
 "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

[image]

Tried adding this as well:

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

But Still When i am trying to see crash report after clicking Add Sdk in Firebase it is always showing me :

[image]

I am stuck here.

I have also tryied few more steps like:
> Changing Debug Information Format to "Drawft with DSYM file" (debug and release both) in build setting.
> Cleaning project

```
> Reinstalled pods

> Restart My mac

> Deleting Derived data

> Deleted app and reinstalled in multiple Simulators 

> Taken ref from below url
```

[Add the Firebase iOS SDK (4.3.0 or higher) or Unity Plugin (6.15.0 or higher), then build, run, and crash your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146933/add-the-firebase-ios-sdk-4-3-0-or-higher-or-unity-plugin-6-15-0-or-higher-t)

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please make sure to disconnect the simulator from the Xcode debugger to see crashes.

Comment: hoe did you resolved it ?I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed app to iPhone and simulator both and disconnect from debug mode and launched 5-6 times.
it solved problem